# How to copy and paste an event in Samsung Galaxy A7 S-Planner running KitKat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, s-planner

I've just bought a Samsung Galaxy A7 running on Android 4.4.4. How do I copy and paste calendar event in S-Planner app?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if this function was added again... sooooo frustrating. 
It existed before:

here's a print screen from my galaxy S2 running android 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean)

[image: Copy event was possible on Android 4.1.2]

Now on my galaxy S4 running android 5.0.1 (Lollipop) it isn't available anymore:

[image: Copy event no longer possible on Android 5.0.1]

For Kit Kat I don't know... don't have any device using it unfortunately. But if it doesn't appear in the popup menu when keeping finger on the event, it's likely that it has been removed since that version.

Hope this helps and that this function will be added again in the future.

Comment: Have you tried the "share via" item, and send it to the planner again?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Functionality has been removed. Time to use a different app!

Comment: It is better if you back your claim using sources. If you cannot, then find screenshots for the earlier version where the functionality or the option is visible and then the newer version where it is missing so that we can verify the credibility of your answer.